# sum and Join with list Generic in c#

Tags: generics, c#-4.0, sum

I want to collect sales gained.

My classes are as follows:

```
 public class PartSell
{
    public string partSellId { get; set; }
    public string partId { get; set; }
}

public class Part
{
    public string partId { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

My data is as follows :

```
 List<Part> lstPart = new List<Part>()
            {
                new Part{partId="100",Price="150000"},
                 new Part{partId="110",Price="180000"},
                  new Part{partId="120",Price="560000"},
                   new Part{partId="150",Price="970000"}
            };

            List<PartSell> lstPartSell = new List<PartSell>()
             {
                 new PartSell{partId="100",partSellId="1"},
                 new PartSell{partId="110",partSellId="2"},
                 new PartSell{partId="110",partSellId="3"},
                 new PartSell{partId="100",partSellId="4"},
                 new PartSell{partId="100",partSellId="5"},
                 new PartSell{partId="100",partSellId="6"},
                 new PartSell{partId="120",partSellId="7"},
                 new PartSell{partId="100",partSellId="8"}
             };
```

How do I calculate the total price for Code 11

Comment: @JonSkeet i think it is "110"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var query = from ll in lstPartSell
                    join lp in lstPart on ll.partId equals lp.partId
                    where ll.partId == "110"
                    select int.Parse(lp.Price);
int sum = query.Sum();
```